# c++ fstream when see string in file

Tags: c++, fstream

I made a code but it doesn't work.Can you help? In code, I wanted to take a line and if code see **//n**, end line.

Here is my example.
File:

```
I love C++! //n
```

My Code:

```
ifstream file("file.txt");
char text[250];
while(file >> text){
  cout << text << " ";
  if(text == "//n"){
    cout << endl;
  } 
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How does this not work?

Comment: Need some clarifications.  A newline is `'\n'` (note, one backslash).  If you are comparing a string to a new line, you would use `"\n"`.

Comment: Also, be aware that you are comparing a *pointer* to an array, `text`, to a *pointer* to a text literal.  They may not exist at the same location.  Prefer `std::string`.  For character arrays, use `strcmp`.

Comment: You may want to use `std::getline` when reading into a char *array*, so you don't overflow the array.  Or you can use `std::string` and not worry about overflowing arrays. :-)

Comment: If you are indeed looking for end-of-line (`\n`) an additional problem is that `operator>>` skips all whitespace, so the end-of-line character will never get stored in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure as to what you are trying to do, however it seems that you want to get a line worth of text. If so, you would want to change

```
char  text[255];

....

if(text == "//n")
```

to

```
std::string  text;

...

if(text == "\n")
```

The array comparison will not compare strings. So use the std::string to allow you to use `==` operator.

As C++ special character codes use a backslash rather than two forward slashes.

However, I'd also suggest using a single char rather than an array (as indexing doesn't seem to be a concern since you only access the first character in it).

Comment: The problem with only changing `text` from array to `std::string`, is that `operator>>` is overloaded to read a word, not an entire line.  Use `std::getline` to read in the text.

Comment: The problem here is that `operator>>` will never read a `'\n'` into text (char or std::string). new line is considered white space and `operator>>` ignores white space.

Comment: I think the asker really means it when they say //n. It's in the datafile. Maybe it's their own custom delimiter for something..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a file a word at a time:

```
ifstream file("file.txt");

std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::stringstream linestream(line);

    std::string       word;
    while(linestream >> word) {
        std::cout << "Word: " << word << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "EOL\n";
}
```

Basically your code has a couple of issues.

1. '//n' is not a special character we all assume you meant '\n'.
2. Most operators that read text from a file will disgard the '\n' character.
   `operator>>` will disguard white space (including \n).
   `getline()` reads the line but drops the \n.
   Thus `'\n'` is never in text to be compared too.
3. Arrays `char text[255]` will convert themselves into pointers easily.
   Thus the comparison you are doing compares two pointers. This will never be equal.
   You need a type that does something smart with `==` so that you compare the text.
   For this you should use `std::string`.

As a good style guide.

Never put `using namespace std;` in your code. It causes more trouble when  you have anything but a simple bit of throwaway code. And using it in simple throwaway code is a bad habit that will catch up to you someday.

The reason `std` (as well as others) is short and not `standard` is so that prefixing it items from the standard library is not burdensome.

```
std::cout << text << " "; // not hard.
std::cout << std::endl;
```

There is no real reason to use `std::endl` (debugging being an exception I suppose). In normal situations the extra flush it adds will generally cause the output to slow down perceptibly. So prefer to use `'\n'` unless you specifically want to force a flush.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, your code compares pointers, instead of comparing strings (as noted also in the other answer):

```
if(text == "//n")
{
    ...
}
```

Here `text` is a pointer (actually, an array of `char`, but in this context it's equivalent to a pointer), and `"//n"` also is a pointer (also an array). Comparing two pointers is not what you want.

To fix your code so it compares strings, one of the things your code compares should be a string instead of a pointer. To mark `"//n"` as a string, append `s` to it:

```
if(text == "//n"s)
{
    ...
}
```

This is a bit obscure; another solution is to make `text` a string (as described in the other answer):

```
std::string text;
```